# jQuery not initializing

Tags: jquery, accordion

jQuery Vertical Accordion from Design Chemical isn't loading!
I'm having trouble getting the jQuery Vertical Accordion from Design Chemical Menu to work and I'm sure it's something obvious, but forgive me, I am new to jQuery and not too familiar with Javascript in general.

Basically the plugin won't load and I get only the boring looking lists and not a nice Accordion menu, as intended :(

When I try 'Hello World' to test Javascript, it works fine, but the accordion eludes me.

Please - what am I doing wrong?

My header:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
                       $('.accordion-1').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'hover',
                        autoClose: true,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        menuClose: false,
                        speed: 'medium',
                        showCount: true,

                        autoExpand: true,
                        cookie  : 'dcjq-accordion-1',
                        classExpand  : 'dcjq-current-parent',

                        menuClose: false    
                    });
});
</script>

       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <script>window.html5 || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
```

This is the body of the document:

```
<body>

    <div class="header-container">
        <header class="wrapper clearfix">
            <h1 class="title">h1.title</h1>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="main wrapper clearfix">

<aside>
    <ul id="accordion-1" class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</aside>

        </div> <!-- #main -->
    </div> <!-- #main-container -->

    <div class="footer-container">
        <footer class="wrapper">
            <h3>footer</h3>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>   
</body>
```

I should mention I also tried initializing with this code, as opposed to the above:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#accordion-1').dcAccordion();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are not loading jQuery anywhere. I'm not familiar with jQuery Vertical Accordion but from the name I take it that it needs jQuery.

Comment: Aaaah - you're right. I must've deleted it while tidying up code or just being a confused old fart - thanx :)

Comment: @Timo Some advice, there's typically 2 common areas where you should place your `<script>` tags: 1. In front of the closing `</head>` tag.  or 2. in front of the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanx for the tip Timo :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following script block under the head tag, solved the issue:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
```

And yes, that's a bit embarrasing :)